# Optional argument to replace variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, variables, host

How can I pass an optional argument to a bash script that will replace an existing variable in the script? For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#hostfinder.sh
#Find hosts in current /24 network

subnet=$(hostname -i | cut -d. -f1,2,3)

for j in \
    $(for i in $subnet.{1..255}; do host $i; done | grep -v not | cut -d" " -f5)
do ping -c1 -w 1 $j; done | grep -i from | cut -d" " -f3,4,5 | tr ':' ' ' | \
sed -e 's/from/Alive:/'
```

This will grab the IP of the current host, run a reverse lookup against possible neighbors, ping test any hostnames it finds, and display an output similar to this:

```
Alive: host1.domain (10.64.17.23)
Alive: host2.domain (10.64.17.24)
...
```

Call me crazy, but it's way faster than nmap and spits out a nice list.

Anyway, I'd like to optionally pass the first three octets of any class C network address to the $subnet variable as the $1 argument when executing the script. For example:

```
./hostfinder.sh 10.20.0
```

My first thought was to try something like $subnet=$1, but I assume that will not work. I'm not really interested in re-writing the script to be more elegant or anything, I am mostly just curious about what I put in the subject line.

Comment: nmap is meant to do a completely different thing.

Comment: nmap can do a lot of things, though. :)

Comment: Also, I think a ping sweep with nmap goes something like this:  nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254

Comment: Did `subnet=$1` not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replace:

```
subnet=$(hostname -i | cut -d. -f1,2,3)
```

with:

```
case $# in  
  0) subnet=$(hostname -i | cut -d. -f1,2,3);;
  1) subnet="${1}";;
  *) echo "To many arguments" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

- `$#` is the number of command line arguments
- This is less elegant as `getopt` but easy to understand and extend.

Comment: Thank you. I will play with this and respond.

Comment: That worked like a champ. Thanks a lot! I can extend it with more options for class A or B now. This will turn into a nice portable sweeper where I don't have nmap installed or when nmap -sP just doesn't seem to work on certain subnets with hosts I need to inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getopt, to read from the options in the command line, and then set your variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would you mind sharing a bit of an example, please?

Answer (score -1):

Like LtWorf suggested, try using `getopt`. Its read the options and its arguments from the command line.

You can find a great example of `getopt` usage here:
[getopt usage example](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt)